# Run script on GCP Dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, pipeline, apache-beam

I'm starting to try Google Cloud Dataflow, after classic `wordcount` example, I wrote my own script:

```
import argparse
import sys

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io import ReadFromText
from apache_beam.io import WriteToText
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions


class Split(beam.DoFn):

    def process(self, element):
        (numfact, bag, type, owner, 
         main_owner, client) = element.splt('\t')

        return [{
            'numfact': int(numfact),
            'type': type,
            'owner': owner
        }]


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('--input')
parser.add_argument('--output')

known_args, extra_args = parser.parse_known_args(sys.argv[1:])

options = PipelineOptions(extra_args)
p = beam.Pipeline(options=options)
print(known_args)
print(extra_args)
csv_lines = (p | "Load" >> ReadFromText(known_args.input, skip_header_lines=1) | "Process" >> beam.ParDo(Split()) | "Write" >> WriteToText(known_args.output))
```

Here a sample from input file:

```
Numfact BAG TYPE    OWNER   MAIN OWNER  CLIENT
728632636   CNT Alternativos    Kramer Ortiz    ACCIDENTES PERSONALES TELETICKET    Rimac
704845964   CNT Alternativos    Kramer Ortiz    SOAT    Canal
701387639   CNT SIN ASIGNAR Sin asignar WEB VEHICULOS   Canal
692571746   CNT Concesionarios  Kramer Ortiz    WEB VEHICULOS   Canal
682823453   CNT Alternativos    Kramer Ortiz    WEB VEHICULOS   Canal
682823452   CNT Alternativos    Kramer Ortiz    WEB VEHICULOS   Canal
682823451   CNT Alternativos    Kramer Ortiz    WEB VEHICULOS   Canal
682823454   CNT Alternativos    Kramer Ortiz    WEB VEHICULOS   Canal
706853395   CNT Alternativos    Kramer Ortiz    ACCIDENTES PERSONALES - WEB Canal
706466281   CNT Alternativos    Kramer Ortiz    SOAT    Canal
```

Finally, I call this to execute like this (file is saved as .txt):

```
python -m beam --input gs://dummy_bucket/data_entry/pcd/pcd_ensure.txt --output gs://dummy_bucket/outputs --runner DataflowRunner --project dummyproject-268120 --temp_location gs://dummy_bucket/tmp --region us-central1
```

After this, it shows prints on console, but does not register execution in DataFlow console.

**Update**

This is how console looks like:

```
(gcp) gocht@~/script$ python -m beam --input gs://dummy_bucket/data_entry/pcd/pcd_ensure.txt --output gs://dummy_bucket/outputs --runner DataflowRunner --project dummyproject-268120 --temp_location gs://dummy_bucket/tmp --region us-central1
Namespace(input='gs://dummy_bucket/data_entry/pcd/pcd_ensure.txt', output='gs://dummy_bucket/outputs')   ['--runner', 'DataflowRunner', '--project', 'dummyproject-268120', '--temp_location', 'gs://dummy_bucket/tmp', '--region', 'us-central1']
```

This only shows prints placed on code script.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide the output of the command ?

Comment: @Pievis updated.

Comment: first time I see the python version but could the p.run().wait_until_finish() be missing in the code ?

Comment: @Pievis worked dude! So simple, so efective. Consider post it as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I've helped ! I'm following your advice and putting it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the answer is in the comment, writing it here also :)

You need to actually make the pipeline run by performing:

```
p.run().wait_until_finish()
```

If you feel stuck and you are not sure what's wrong, try to have a look at the examples provided [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/professional-services/tree/master/examples/dataflow-python-examples/dataflow_python_examples) - the java version really helped me a lot when starting with dataflow :)

Answer (score 1):

You will need

```
result = p.run()
```

at the end of your file to run the pipeline.

Basically I think you have constructed your pipeline but didn't really ask to run it.